# Best way to build color matrix with different color in contiguous items

Tags: asp.net, .net, algorithm, c#-4.0

I have interesting case I have table in database where I store some color in hex format.
I make a query to this table and getting a list with different colors from database.
I need to show a query result to user in "matrix style" for example 8 row and 10 columns.
But result matrix shouldn't have the same or similar hue in contiguous items matrix items.
What the best way to do it ?

[image: example of results]

Comment: define "contiguous". Can similar colors be adjacent diagonally? Can we put two similar colors one on top of the other?

Comment: In good case answer on your 2 questions is NO, all colors around one item should be different, or looks like they have big visual difference.  But for me it looks like very hard case.

Answer (score 1):

You could start with a very simple algorithm:

1. Place all colours at random
2. Find a bad entry (i.e. one where the colour is not very different to a neighbour)
3. Swap this entry with another random location (but only if the swap makes things better)
4. Repeat several times

Comment: Yes good point, but it looks like this algorithm will work very long time or not ?

Comment: Your matrix doesn't seem too big so I would start by setting it to repeat 1000 times, say, and see how the results look.  My guess would be that this would look fine and take a tiny amount of time - but I am often wrong!

Comment: Yes it is try, but just image this on big solution ? i am wonder does any one done it before ?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a [Vertex Coloring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring#Vertex_coloring) of a planar graph.  The good news is that since your graph is planar you really only need four colors, the bad news is that finding the coloring is not always easy.  If your graphs are always that size, though, a recursive solution with backtracking will probably be sufficient.

Comment: How to build this graph in .net on c# ?